# Commerce Shipping - Calculate the shipping cost as a percentage

Tags: rules, commerce

I am looking to calculate the shipping cost as a percentage of each item in the order.

In addition to that I would like there to be an extra shipping option which is a flat rate that can be added on as well.

So the shipping rate is always a percentage of the order total, and then also an additional flat rate charge can be added on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to code that yourself, I don't think the existing shipping functionality (or any of the add-on modules) will do that. There's an example module included with [Commerce Shipping](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) that outlines the process for development, it's a pretty easy one

Answer (score 0):

there's also this tutorial for anyone who runs into this. Sorry for just posting the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A1Yyam3Ico

Answer (score 0):

Commerce shipping + commerce flat rate can give you the flat rate part of your shipping.

For the % based you can add it with tax module and make a shipping "tax". You can add a condition that the order has the selected flat rate for it to apply.

This is a pretty easy solution but won't display the correct price in selection. If you need that you would need to code it yourself.